# Show only file names using rsync --recursive on Python?

Tags: python, rsync

I am using rsync recursive to all the files in that directory (including all the files the sub-directories too):

```
rathi/20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt
rathi/20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt
rathi/20090729.02s4.2_sequence.txt.gz
rathi/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19.tar.gz
rathi/SRR002321.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002322.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002323.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002324.fastq
rathi/SRR002324.fastq.bz2
rathi/human_g1k_v37.fasta.gz
rathi/s_1_1_sequence.txt
rathi/s_1_sequence.txt
rathi/tesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttt.txt
rathi/test_data.tar.gz
rathi/Homo_sapiens
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Archives
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Archives/ok.txt
```

I have one problem with this. The directories listing such as

```
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Archives
```

are no use to me. I only want to get the path with file. Is this kind of thing is possible along with rsync only? I am using `subprocess.call` to call rsync in Python.

So, I want my output to be like this:

```
rathi/20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt
rathi/20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt
rathi/20090729.02s4.2_sequence.txt.gz
rathi/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19.tar.gz
rathi/SRR002321.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002322.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002323.fastq.bz2
rathi/SRR002324.fastq
rathi/SRR002324.fastq.bz2
rathi/human_g1k_v37.fasta.gz
rathi/s_1_1_sequence.txt
rathi/s_1_sequence.txt
rathi/tesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttt.txt
rathi/test_data.tar.gz
rathi/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Archives/ok.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip everything which is below a directory, you can do

```
rsync -avz --exclude '*/' source_directory destination_directory
```

If you want skip all the empty directories, you can use

```
rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs source_directory destination_directory
```

But it is not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve. You want to skip directories, but not the files in them, where do you want to sync them then if you didn't sync the directory? Or is this just about the output on the screen?

If you just want to change the output on the screen, you can pipe it through grep, i.e.

```
rsync -avz source_directory destination_directory | grep "\."
```

Then you will only see lines with a `.`. Note that you have to escape `.`, as it otherwise stands for a wildcard. Of course, this assumes that you don't have any dots in your directory names.

Comment: Please specify what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Actually, this is just about the output on the screen. I have updated my question with the expected output.

Comment: Yes, its' working but with a slight problem that you have already specified. There can be dot in some directory name. Is there a way to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use os.walk , It will list all files.

```
import os
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('rathi')
       print filenames
```

It will list all file names.

Comment: I am trying to access file of remote server using rsync.

Answer (score -1):

May option --filter help you?

rsync --filter=- */